# Editing data using Jquery, Json, Jquery UI dialog and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-ui

I currently have a screen where I display a number of records with an Add, Edit, Delete link.

Currently the Add link displays a modal window with a form that was rendered to the page using a PartialView. I can enter data into the form and click save and the data will be sent to the server using the Jquery forms plug-in. Works like a charm.

My question is about the edit functionality. What are the best practices in this case? Should I use the same partial view I am using for adding records or should I render a separate one for edit purposes (only the post url would change). What is the best way to bind the Json data to the form when editing records?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using separate files for adding and editing, you will have clean code to debug and upgrade.

And as you said you can use same file and change the post url. I would say the former one is a best practice. even though code reusing is a best practice too, as it is not easy to maintain on a large application when working on the client side.

But on the server side you can reuse the code from adding a record for updating a record.

Comment: Thanks! I think I will go the "less partials" route to keep less files.